# Saving the state of the screen when orientation is changed

Tags: android

I'm displaying the current location address on the screen. I was told to add (android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation")  in manifest file to store the context(address).It works fine,but after adding this line, the screen orientation is not changing . If i remove this line, then the orientation works good but the address disappears on changing the orientation.
If anyone knows how to solve this, then pls comment on it.

Thank you.

Comment: @Spoorti: Hi.. Try this along with `android:configChanges` in android Manifest.. `android:screenOrientation="unspecified"`

Comment: @Spoorti: Ur activity is recreating when the orientation changes.. Add above code in android manifest for that activity.. It will work fine..

Comment: No..... result is still the same

Comment: @Spoorti: Orientation is not changing or u are not gettin the address.?

Comment: I'm getting address. But if i put android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" then orientation is not changing.

Comment: <activity android:name=".activity1"
   android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.Translucent"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:screenOrientation="unspecified">
  </activity>

Comment: @Spoorti: The Above code im using.. It allows to change the orientation but it wont recreates the activity..

Answer (score 2):

Use android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in manifest

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the data, as the orientation gets changed the screen is drawn new. i.e. onDestroy gets called and then onCreate() gets called again. The following link has more info on how to save the data.

[Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)

[Restoring state of TextView after screen rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179686/restoring-state-after-screen-rotation)

Comment: I've gone through these sites. Accordingly if i edit my code, then address gets stored, but the orientation remains the same, horizontal or vertical.

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate the screen, Android redraws the entire activity to for the new orientation. This involves calling onCreate() again, which is why your address is disappearing. Take a look at [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29), an Activity method you can override to store anything you need to hang on to when the activity is closed and reopened. Just package up your data in the Bundle, and then you have access to it again in the Bundle in onCreate().

This sounds overly complex, but this is the correct way to handle it. Android can close your activity for any number of reasons - the screen rotation is just a really easy one to test. If it works for the rotation, then it'll likely work for other situations like low memory, etc.

Comment: I ve used onSaveInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState)  and onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState), but still location address is disappearing.

Comment: @Spoorti Could you post code showing how you're saving / restoring the address currently?

Comment: @Override
     public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
  savedInstanceState.putString("MyString",     result.toString());     
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);    
   
  }    
 
 @Override    
 public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle     savedInstanceState) {    
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString"); 
  }

Comment: I'm a new user. I dont know how to format code. Could u pls help yourself?

Comment: In the above code, result.toString() gives the location address.