# How to permanently change a textView using editText from the app

Tags: text, view, edit

I am trying to change the text of a text view to that of the inputted text from the edit text.  i can do this easily with setText, yet when i exit and reenter the app, the textView has reset to its original value.  I want to permanently change the textview value so when i exit and reenter the app, the textview is the same value i entered in the EditText.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  final Button clicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
  final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
  final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
  final Editable str = (Editable) input.getText();
    clicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             text.setText(str.toString());

        }} );
```

Answer (score 0):

The android framework automatically saves the state of certain views when your activity is destroyed. Unfortunately, TextView is not one of those views (but EditText is).

See this question:
[Restoring state of TextView after screen rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179686/restoring-state-of-textview-after-screen-rotation)

You should learn more about the activity lifecycle, specifically about recreating an activity:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html