# TextView value doesn't restore when screen is rotated - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-orientation, onconfigurationchanged

I have looked at other posts and tried out the solutions suggested but none have worked for me. I have a simple app, that has a button and Textview and when the user presses the button the value in TextView will increase by 1. (The textview only has numbers).

I have different layout for my portrait and landscape mode and I was able to freeze the value on screen orientation by using this code in my XML `android:freezesText="true"`. However, the problem that I am having now is that on screen orientation when the user presses the button to increament the value of TextView by 1, the value in textview starts from 0. For example

For example on portrait mode the value is 23, when the user rotates the screen to landscape and presses the button the value will go back to 1. How do I make the value start from 23.

Below is my code;

Portrait layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/textview"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/up" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Landspace layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/textview"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/up" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java code

```
int counter = 0;
TextView textview;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview );


        final Button up = (Button)findViewById(R.id.up);
        up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter++;
                textview.setText("" + counter);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Try this.. (restore the state of the count)
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179686/restoring-state-of-textview-after-screen-rotation>

Comment: I already been on the provided post and tried the solutions but it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you somehow reload the activity parameters when going from portrait to landscape, which will accordingly resets `counter` value to `0` again when rotating. you may try to make it `static` variable to avoid conflicting.

```
private static int counter = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, making the counter static did the job!!

Answer (score 3):

You need to override `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and write the application state values you want to change to the Bundle parameter like this.This will save your data even the device orientation changed.

```
int count = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      UI();

}

public void UI() {

    textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview );

    final Button up = (Button)findViewById(R.id.up);
    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count++;
            textview.setText("" + counter);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    UI();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    savedInstanceState.putString("key_name", textview.getText().toString());
    savedInstanceState.putInt("count", ""+count);

}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);{

     textview.setText("" + savedInstanceState.getString("key_name"));
     count = savedInstanceState.getInt("count")

}
```

Comment: I tried this code but when the screen is rotated and the button is pressed the value of textview starts from 0.

Comment: Now the app force closes.

Comment: @Android Okay am wrongly said that.Now save the count value also in `savedInstanceState`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Yugesh, I have given +1 to your answer because of your effort but it turns out, as pointed out by Muhammed Refaat I had to change my counter variable to static.

Comment: @Android Fine.For more about save activity state during Screen rotation.Refer this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android).I got Solution from there when i faced a problem like this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are incrementing a wrong variable.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    count++;
    textview.setText("" + counter);
}
```

Also, do this in the onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview );
    textview.setText("" + counter);  //Add this line to automatically set the value


    final Button up = (Button)findViewById(R.id.up);
    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count++;
            textview.setText("" + counter);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I had to rewrite the code here so I forgot to put er on count, sorry about that.