# Why does LiveData not restore original UI state after screen rotation?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-room

I'm working on an app and am using the android architecture components. I have a ViewModel that I am using to store and manage the UI data. I have an activity that displays a list of text items that are loaded from the Room database as LiveData. The views containing the LiveData are editable. Basically, it's a RecyclerView containing EditTexts.

What I'm wondering is the scenario where the user changes one of the EditText's values, and then something happens that causes the activity to restart, such as a configuration change. From what I understood, the activity is created again which means the onChanged() callback gets invoked again and the list gets repopulated with the original LiveData that came from the database. Because of that, I expected the EditText (the one whose text was edited by the user) to display the original LiveData that was assigned to it before the user changed the text. However, when I rotated my device's screen, the edited text remained.

This is what I wanted, but I didn't think this was the default behavior. I'd like to know why the edited text persisted after the configuration change since it was never saved to the database. Is this just a special property of EditTexts? This user's post describes something similar happening where their EditTexts retained their most recent states after a screen rotation while their TextViews were cleared: [Restoring state of TextView after screen rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179686/restoring-state-of-textview-after-screen-rotation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my question in this codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles/#6

> Some UI elements, including EditText, save their state using their own onSaveInstanceState implementation. This state is restored after a process is killed the same way it's restored after a configuration change.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7990543/4293962). But yes, edittexts will automatically handle state by default. Also, in your scenario the livedata didn't load the value again because the database did not change.